# Reproducing legacy binary file with Python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a legacy binary file format in Python 2.7 (the file will be read by a C program).

Is there a way to output the hex representation of integers to a file? I suspect I'll have to roll my own (not least because I don't think Python has the concept of short int, int and long int), but just in case I thought I'd ask. If I have a list:

```
[0x20, 0x3AB, 0xFFFF]
```

Is there an easy way to write that to a file so a hex editor would show the file contents as:

```
20 00 AB 03 FF FF
```

(note the endianness)?

Comment: You can use the built-in `hex` function for some of this, and bitmask for the endianness if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some specific formatting needs, I think that using `hex` is out - you don't need the prefix. We use `format` instead.

```
data = [0x20, 0x3AB, 0xFFFF]

def split_digit(n): 
    """ Bitmasks out the first and second bytes of a <=32 bit number. 
        Consider checking if isinstance(n, long) and throwing an error. 
    """
    return (0x00ff & n, (0xff00 & n) >> 8)

[hex(x) + ' ' + hex(y) for x, y in [split_digit(d) for d in data]]
# ['0x20 0x0', '0xab 0x3', '0xff 0xff']

with open('myFile.bin', 'wb') as fh: 
    for datum in data: 
        little, big = split_digit(datum)
        fh.write(format(little, '02x'))
        fh.write(format(big, '02x'))
```

...or something like that? You'll need to change the formatting a bit, I bet.